# kernel size of 0,0 in cv gaussian blur?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to understand what setting `ksize = 0,0` in `cv2.GaussianBlur()` does. In the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gaabe8c836e97159a9193fb0b11ac52cf1), it says

> they can be zero's and then they are computed from `sigma`

What exactly does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

In gaussian filter, we have to determine sigma or standarad deviation of filter.  Sigma determines width of filter(say size of filter). The larger sigma, the more blure image. There are two way to specify width of filter, one is window size and second is sigma. With second way, size of window can be determined mathmatically.
detaield info in this link: [detailed](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10057/gaussian-blur-standard-deviation-radius-and-kernel-size)